# Angular 6 client app deployed on intranet IIS 10 returns Error 0 all the time

Tags: angular, iis, .net-core

I searched through this forum for days now and I'm unable to solve this issue.
Just to describe the environment, I have a Windows 10 box running IIS 10,
client application runs on port 80 and WebService (.NET core 2.0) runs on port 123 .

Client app keeps having an error 0 : Unknown Error, which I understand is CORS issues.

I configured my web service (Server-side) with the following :

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", 
    builder => {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials();
}));
```

and later on, I use

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

My angular 6 application defines a service such as follow :

```
export class SearchService {
    const baseUrl = 'http://drague.karaoke:123/api';
    const searchUrl = this.baseUrl + '/KaraokeSongs/search';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    search(term) {
        if (!term) {
            term = ""
        }

        var restResponse:SearchSong[];
        const parameters = new HttpParams().set('filter', term);

        const headerDict = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Language, Origin, User-Agent',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        });

        console.log(headerDict);

        return this.http.get<SearchSong[]>(this.searchUrl, { headers: headerDict, params: parameters });
  }
```

When I try with Postman, everything is fine, service responds as expected.  Same thing when I run ng-serve --proxy-config with the following configuration :

```
{
   "/api" : {
    "target": "http://drague.karaoke:123",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

When I deploy the client on IIS, I can't get it to work.  Any ideas are welcome, I'm really getting desperate...

Useful things to know about the environment :

- It is strictly http calls (no Https)
- It is an Intranet.  Routing to the server is done by the WIFI router, which exposes the domain 'drague.karaoke'.
- client deployed on http://drague.karaoke:80
- Web service on http://drague.karaoke:123/api

Thanks for your help...

Rejean

Comment: Is there authentication for the api? I’ve noticed the CORS headers don’t work as expected when authentication is involved.

Comment: No, it is anonymous...

Comment: Have you tried applying EnableCors(“CorsPolicy”) attribute at your controller class or action method?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also, both on Method and Class...  It doesn't change anything...

Comment: Run a tool like Fiddler, or use Developer Tools of your web browser to see what exactly are the requests/responses from the browser to IIS. Only then you know what are the actual errors and you might find existing threads to help.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of tests and trials.   Finally, it appeared that the port 123 is a reserved port (for NTP).  I changed the port to 81 and everything went fine...

Curiously, Firefox didn't gave any hint on that, Fiddler and Charles neither...

Thanks to Chrome (and Stack Overflow) who helped me figure it out....